# Why does Trello always return 12 search results after search?

Tags: trello

Why does Trello always return 12 results after search?

I have 25 "to do" items but when I search only 12 items are displayed. 
Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Returning 12 results is a limitation of the search feature at the moment. Using a more detailed search might yield better results.